# Uploading docker logs from ec2 instance to S3 before shutdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Currently using an auto scaling group (ASG) on AWS, and sometimes a docker container running in an EC2 instance exits due to some ambiguous reason and the instance may get removed from the ASG. This makes debugging the failure difficult since the ASG terminates the instance and therefore erasing all the evidence of what went wrong. 
So, is there a way to write docker logs to S3 before it exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the logs to cloudwatch and export to s3 if needed.

Below is the process,

Add your credentials to,

```
/etc/init/docker.override
```

With,

```
env AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
env AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

and restart your docker service.

> docker run -it --log-driver="awslogs" --log-opt
>   awslogs-region="us-east-1" --log-opt awslogs-group="log-group"
>   --log-opt awslogs-stream="log-stream" ubuntu:14.04 bash

This way docker sends all logs to cloudwatch.

Hope it help[s.